# A version on Gronwall's inequality with interval $[-\tau, t]$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\tau$ and $T$ be positive constants and $u:[-\tau,T] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a Riemann integrable function. Assume that for all $t \in [0, T],$
$$u(t) \leq a+b \int_{t-\tau}^{t}u(s)ds.$$
Is it true that then $u(t) \leq a e^{b \tau}$ for for all $t \in [0, T]$?

Comment: @Sebastion What did you attempted?

Comment: @Avenger The above statement is not an exercise. I have reduced a longer proof into the above statement. If I can prove that, then I will be done. I am looking for an idea/clue on how to tackle the above. Not sure at all if the statement is true.

Comment: @Avenger The problem I have is that if I define $f(t):= a+b \int_{t-\tau}^t u(s)ds,$ then $u'(t)$ is not $b f(t)$ for all $t \in [0,T]$ as it would be in the standard Gronwall inequality, where the integral starts at $0$.

Comment: Ok, I undersatnd.